# how to add multiples markers on google map without affecting UI thread?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using an `Asyntask` to call a service, returning 1k to 2k coordinates(lat,long).

When I am adding them as markers on a map, using a `for(...)` loop, it takes lot of time and the UI thread is going slower and slower.

Also I tried using thread but no luck.

What I need: adding markers using a background process without affecting UI thread

My code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;      
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
    LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 4));
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.placeholder))
            .title("Current Location")
            .position(hcmus)));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    new getLatLong().execute();
}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        addMarker = FacadeLatLong.getLatLong();

        for (LatLng latlng : addMarker
                ) {
            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.flash))
                    .title("Lightning")
                    .position(latlng)));
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to present a question well.

Comment: I format the code and remove the comments. I tried to make the test clearer and more precise